Horrible performance when downloading from CIFS mounted drive
I have recently wanted to mount a remote CIFS drive. But i have run into one major issue. The speeds are amazing. Uploading is about 220Mbit/s.. However, downloading has speeds of 5Mbit/s.. Which is mostly unusable. The remote has no problems doing the speed of 220Mbit/s both ways for other people. I am in contact with the remote provider, and it is confirmed there is some issue somewhere. My provider is also aware of this, and change of the main network cable to my server was performed. But no luck.
There have been a lot of tests done. The issue happens on both CIFS & SFTP. Moving the remote location to a different DC was also tried. But no luck. MTR both ways was also performed. But it is all good.
The server and remote or not one hte same LAN.
The bandwith of my server is 250Mbps both ways. And it hardly goes above 70Mpbs. Speedtest shows around 230Mbps both ways too.
The resolution is taking a lot of time. And to speed up the process i figured i would also try my luck here.

Is your client endpoint local to the server (same LAN) or on a remote connection? What about the other clients for whom you say everything is sufficiently fast? If you're remote what's your theoretical network speed for your client endpoint? What's download speed like from sites like speedtest.net? "There have been a lot of tests done" - such as what, and with what results?

The done tests was just testing different protocols and locations, MTRs etc.. I have edited the post to add more details.

Since this happens on multiple protocols, it's likely that there's network configuration to blame here.  (aside from you, say, setting hard cgroupv2 I/O limits that you forgot about ;) That'd be a mistake that could happen to me!)
In my experience, such strangely asymmetric speeds are typically a result of one side dropping packages – especially TCP ACK ones – which is something that happens when a router with built-in firewall with TCP connection tracking is overwhelmed. If there's a cheap consumer router between your host and the clients, you could try restarting that one and see whether speeds are OK for a few moments. If it is, but becomes slower with usage, chances are you simply need a less bad device.
If there's none, it's time to dig deeper into network debugging on your host. Check for dropped packets on the RX and TX queues of your network cards (in /sys/class/net/{interface}/statistics) and errors – watch these numbers as you do a transfer. If you can rule out hardware/driver issues, move on to intermittent TCP success; first, I'd check dmesg for things related to nf_conntrack. If that yields nothing, good ole netstat -s might be insightful: track the number of TCPLostRetransmit.
You'll probably will want to use wireshark remote / tcpdump to analyse which packets get sent.

Well since my server is rented.. I have no control of the network infrastructure. But it is a DC. The must have good  equipment. In the netstat i see that TCPLostRetransmit has got bigger by 7.

in which time, during how much transfer? 7 is not a big number, unless you only transmitted a hundred packets.

I transfered 5GB. It took 22Minutes. It got bigger in total by 15

nah, then it's not that. Does a TCP capture suggest any shenanigans like duplicate or missing packets?

Well i do not have much expirience with tcpdump so i am not sure if i am gonna be able to figure that out.

run a tcpdump session for maybe 20s while you start  doing a slow transfer from another machine), then cancel recording (ctrl-c), and download the recorded file, and open it in your machine in wireshark.

I did that, captured for like a minute on port 445.

excellent. Look at the recording in wireshark. Look for things that are highlighted as broken in red and stuff. I don't have a ready-made recipe here.

I see a significant number of Out-Of-Order, Previus segment not captured, Dup ACK and thats about it.

"previous segment not captured" can be OK if its at the beginning of your recording – things that were done before the recording can't be recorded. Out-of-order really points to a router or a firewall doing ugly things. And duplicate ACKs? Rather unusual.

The errors repeat, and can be seen even near the middle-end of the transfer.

And you have constrained port 445 to authenticated traffic from allowed IPs, and are not in a situation where you're exposing a SMB server to the internet, and a dozen botnets are currently trying dictionary passwords on it, right?

I am the server that's trying to access remote cifs drive. Not the server who is providing cifs drive
